Force mobile navigation menu to remain in open state
I want to apply some custom CSS rules to the navigation menu in WordPress's Twenty Twenty-Four theme. When I click menu, the menu appears. When I right-click and select "Inspect" from the context menu in Firefox or Chrome, the navigation menu closes. How can I get it to remain open?

I asked in the Wordpress Stack Exchange and the question was closed as off-topic.

Show us the code you tried to achieve this.

The element with class wp-block-navigation__responsive-container gets the two additional classes has-modal-open and is-menu-open added via JavaScript, when you open the menu. They get remove again, if you click elsewhere - for example on an element anywhere within dev tools. But if you add those classes yourself via dev tools, they stay until the page gets reloaded.

Thanks to @C3roe for getting me on the right track! I ran this in the console and now my menu stays open!
document.querySelector('.wp-block-navigation__responsive-container')?.classList.add('has-modal-open', 'is-menu-open');

